# Running a process when the target exe displays a gui and modal dialogs

Tags: c#, user-interface, process, modal-dialog

I have an application that I would like to call from C#, using something like:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorDataHandler);
process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputDataHandler);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
```

I know in advance that the application invoked has a gui and may throw up model dialog boxes. The way I am invoking the application the gui will never be needed and will run to completion. A model dialog box is thrown up at the end simply asking the user is they want to close the gui (since it was invoked to run automatically).

Is there a way to invoke the app from c# such that

a) The modal dialog boxes are ignored?
b) No GUI is actually shown?

Ultimtely I want to run the external app with no interruption before it returns control to my app.

EDIT: More clarification. I don't own the 3rd party app, so I have *no* control on how it behaves.

Comment: CreateNoWindow only works for console apps.  GUI apps routinely ignore the requested WindowStyle.  You cannot suppress modal dialogs.  Talk to the owner of this program to get ahead, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but c'est la vie :) The modal dialog at the end has a unique process name, so I think I can raise an event when that process starts and kill it. There is no possibility of the vendor changing anything.